# Do module isomorphisms preserve freeness?

Tags: category-theory, free-modules, module-isomorphism

Let $f$ be module isomorphism $f:M_1 \rightarrow M_2$, with $M_1$ free. Then, is $M_2$ free too? 
*I tried to come up with a proof*:
Let $B_1$ be the basis of $M_1$. Then we know that
$f(B_1)$ is linearly independent. $$f(m_1)=f(\sum r_ib_{1i})=\sum r_if(b_{1i})$$
for any $m_1 \in M_1$ and $b_{1i} \in B_1$.
Considering the fact that $f$ is bijective, is this enough to prove my question?

Comment: for me that was actually the definition of being free, i.e. being isomorphic to a free module. Also, yea, your proof is fine, that is how I actually like to think about a basis (it is an isomorphism from $R^n$)

Comment: Thank you! I just begun studying modules and they're a little too abstract for me sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is correct. In general all properties of objects that make sense must be preserved by isomorphisms. Moreover, in categories that are not small there is a problem with defining equality of objects, since it must by definition the equality is a relation on the class of objects. Since a relation is a subset of the product, it is not well defined when objects form a proper class, in particular in the case of modules.